# Finite Measure: Uncountably Many Masses?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Can a finite measure space have uncountably many disjoint sets with nonvanishing mass:
$$\mu(A_{\lambda})>0\quad(\lambda\in\Lambda:\#\Lambda>\aleph_0)$$
Do you have an example or can you give me a proof, please?

*(My problem is that an argument involving uncountable sums cannot be applied directly.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard argument is to consider
$$
            \Lambda_{n} = \{ \lambda \in \Lambda : \mu(A_{\lambda})\ge 1/n \},\;\;\; n =1,2,3,\cdots .
$$
Because $\mu$ is a finite measure, then $\Lambda_{n}$ must be a finite (or empty) set. Then you argue that
$$
                           \Lambda = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\Lambda_{n}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible. Any uncountable sum of strictly positive terms is infinite, so there are at most countably many such subsets of any *finite* measure space. Now decompose your $\sigma$-finite space into a countable disjoint union of finite spaces. The collection of all of your disjoint masses in the $\sigma$-finite space is a countable union of countable sets, so it is countable.

Comment: There are at most countably many disjoint subsets of measure $>0$ inside a set of finite measure. So, all but countably many intersections with a finite space will have measure zero ...

Comment: @orangeskid That sounds like a very similar argument to this one to me.

Comment: @Ian: Yeah but the problem is that one just cannot argue with uncountable sums as their union may not be measurable on the one hand and measures decompose only into countably many disjoints on the other hand. So the argument with the uncountable sum has to be changed slightly to make it work and that is what is my problem here!

Comment: @orangeskid: It sounds very similar to me, too, however, as pointed out to Ian my problem is to give a rigorous argument for the finite measure space case. Surely, any uncountable family of nonvanishing numbers cannot be summable but the flaw is that we just cannot take such an argument directly for measures!

Comment: I set the question more specifically to the finite case ;)